# javascript what is wrong with this "for" loop syntax?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Can someone please help me?

I am currently learning Javascript, and I don't understand what's wrong with the following piece of code:

```js
var names = ["vasco", "joão", "francisco", "rita", "manuel"];
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++); {
  console.log("I know someone called " + names[i] + ".");
}
```

Comment: jslint or jshint. Get a tool that can help you debug.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in JavaScript are zero-indexed. That means the element in the very first position is at index `0`. To target that element, you can refer to it like `names[0]`. In your loop, you are iterating while `i < 4`, meaning once `i` becomes 4, the loop stops and does not continue. So you are only calling `console.log` 4 times. A common practice when iterating through an array is to say `i < names.length`. Also there are a couple syntax errors as others have pointed out. Below is a working version.

```
for (var i=0; i < names.length; i++) {
    console.log ("I know someone called"+" "+names[i]+"."); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

because you terminate the for loop by semicolon(;) ,so for loop is seperated by its block .

then,

**Ques1.** what'll do next when code is run?

**Ans.** when execution comes to for loop, loop executes **untill the value of i goes to 4** . then , the next block statement is executed.

**Ques2.** Why "manuel" is print in o/p?

**Ans.**  answer is simple ,because  foor loop terminates when **value of i goes to 4** , so

```
console.log("I know someone called " + names[i] + ".");         //it prints the arr[4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have ; at the end of your for, just remove it

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the semicolon after the for to be:

```
var names=["vasco","joão","francisco","rita","manuel"];

for ( var i=0; i <5 ; i ++) {
    console.log ("I know someone called"+" "+names[i]+"."); 
}
```

also the condition i<4 is the stopping the last case

Answer (score 0):

there are two issues with the code you wrote ,

1- you have a semi-colon after the condition `for(condition);`
   which result in the loop not doing anything

2- you are off by one, last element of the array has index `4` 
   condition should be `(i <= 4)` or `(i < array.length)`

```
var names = ["vasco", "joão", "francisco", "rita", "manuel"];
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
  console.log("I know someone called " + names[i] + ".");
}
```